# How do I select an ID from text file and output results using only jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax script that loads data from a csv file. How do I select the ID column and output the result? For example the following csv file contains:

```
ID,State,City,ZipCode
1,Florida,Tampa,33601
2,Ohio,Westerville,43081
3,Indiana,Westfield,46032
```

I want to select ID 2 and output Ohio,Westerville,43081. The following code I have so far outputs everything. I want to be able to select my id and output the result without using a database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <title>Parsing CSV Files</title>
  <script>

        (function($) {

  //$(document).ready(function() {

  'use strict';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'csv_data.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
  }).done(successFunction);

  function successFunction(data) {
    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table = '<table>';
    for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '<thead>';
        table += '<tr>';
      } else {
        table += '<tr>';
      }
      var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
      for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
        if (singleRow === 0) {
          table += '<th>';
          table += rowCells[rowCell];
          table += '</th>';
        } else {
          table += '<td>';
          table += rowCells[rowCell];
          table += '</td>';
        }
      }
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '</tr>';
        table += '</thead>';
        table += '<tbody>';
      } else {
        table += '</tr>';
      }
    }
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    $('body').append(table);
  }

  // });

})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>

<body>
Content Displayed Here
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can split you response and check the ID

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: could you please add your response String **data** ?

Comment: not sure how to do that. The only thing I have available is what I posted above. I'm new to ajax and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO it seperately, start with `thead` then `tbody`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'csv_data.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);

function successFunction(data) {
    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table = '<table>';
    for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {

       // This is only for the head : THE FIRST LINE before \n
       var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
       if (singleRow === 0) {
           table += '<thead>';
           table += '<tr>';
           for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
               table += '<th>';
               table += rowCells[rowCell];
               table += '</th>';                
           }
           table += '</ tr>';
           table += '</ thead>';
       }else{
           // To select an ID
           if(rowCells[0] == '2'){
               table += '<tbody>';
               table += '<tr>';

               for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
                   table += '<td>';
                   table += rowCells[rowCell];
                   table += '</td>';
               }
               table += '</ tr>';
               table += '</ tbody>';
           }
       }
    }
   table += '</table>';
   $('body').append(table);
```

}

Comment: thank you for your response. Is there a way to change the data dynamically say if i want to update csv file and change id to something else. how would I make that load dynamically? Basically how would the html file load with the changes from the csv file?

Comment: Call this ajax function every time that the CSV file changes or you may add a `setIntervale()` function to call the AJAX function continuously. If you want to change data from the csv file, consider to do it on the back end or you can generate a new csv file with the ajax result.

Answer (score 0):

as you are already splitting the lines at `allRows[singleRow].split(',')`,

You can use that value to check the Id (2).

change your function something like

```js
var data = 'ID,State,City,ZipCode\r1,Florida,Tampa,33601\r2,Ohio,Westerville,43081\r3,Indiana,Westfield,46032';
$(document).ready(function(){
 successFunction(data);
});

function successFunction(data) {
    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table = '<table>';
    for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '<thead>';
        table += '<tr>';
      } else {
        table += '<tr>';
      }
      var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
      for (var rowCell = 1; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
        if (singleRow === 0) {
          table += '<th>';
          table += rowCells[rowCell];
          table += '</th>';
        } else if(rowCells[0]=="2"){
          table += '<td>';
          table += rowCells[rowCell];
          table += '</td>';
        }
      }
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '</tr>';
        table += '</thead>';
        table += '<tbody>';
      } else {
        table += '</tr>';
      }
    }
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    $('body').append(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for your help. One last thing. Is it possible to just output: "Ohio,Westerville,43081" instead of: "2 Ohio Westerville 43081"

Comment: @user3683976 yes you can, check, I have updated the answer

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically load the data if I want to change the id to something else? How would the HTML file load dynamically if a value in the csv file is changed? That way i don't have to change anything in the HTML file

Comment: @user3683976 so you mean to say that, tomorrow instead of **2** you might want to print data for let say id **9** without changing the javascript code, Am i correct ?

Comment: that's correct. I just want to be able to update the csv file and load the data by selecting an id without having to go into the script and manually putting which id i want to load. I would still select the id want to load just don't want it to go into the script and put it in manually

Comment: If you want to just load always only 1 id then you must send only one line in CSV, and remove condition from JS code

Comment: wondering if I should incorporate some kind of a search feature here and have it filter by id

Comment: You can pass id with you ajax response and show only that data out of all

Comment: could you please add **console.log(data)** at first line in **successFunction** and from console can you add that response in your code first ?

Comment: Now you can see the ajax response in you browser console ,just put that in your question.

Comment: Alpesh, If I have a span tag with a value how would that load? i.e <span id=“test”>123</span>. So basically the span tag would load from the JavaScript with the value from the text file. I have a variable: vat = testId document.getElementbyId(“test”); Please help :)

Comment: @user3683976 from where you load this **<span id=“test”>123</span>**

Comment: <span id=“test”>123</span> is within the html page but needs loaded from the JavaScript. The variable that I have: var testId = document.getElementbyId(“test”); and for some reason that’s not loading. Instead of saying: else if(rowCells[0]=="2") is there a way to call var = testId document.getElementbyId(“test”); How would I call that variable and spit out the result value that’s in the span tag?

Comment: @user3683976 have you tried like **document.getElementById("test").innerHTML** ? could you please create fiddle with html content ?

Comment: so basically the span id would load dynamically when the JavaScript is run but it’s not loading. var = testId; document.getElementbyId(“test”).innerHTML = x;
is in the JavaScript. So whatever is in the span tag that would get loaded.

Comment: @user3683976 I am not getting (***span id would load dynamically when the JavaScript is run**) without your code.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have a variable:  var x = $('#test').text(); document.getElementbyId(“test”).innerHTML = x; when you look at the fiddle js is not loading the result when that variable is called. https://jsfiddle.net/dude12go8/5hgtg2rL/5/

Comment: @user3683976 is will not load the result because your ajax call is not correct, https://jsfiddle.net/5hgtg2rL/10/, check this I have alert the value, and instead of **csv_data.csv** you should add complete **url** to validate the result

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there anyway to hide the alert without popping up like that?

Comment: remove that alert line

Comment: Thanks Alpesh. That worked, my final question is how do I hide the first column ID,State,City,ZipCode 1,Florida,Tampa,33601 2,Ohio,Westerville,43081 so basically hide the ID column and only spit out state city and zipcode column. So basically the ID column would be just hidden but the data would still be there but just hidden. The example you provided me: var data = 'ID,State,City,ZipCode\r1,Florida,Tampa,33601\r2,Ohio,Westerville,43081'; $(document).ready(function(){ successFunction(data); }); is done manually. I don’t want to have to write it in manually in the variable given above.

Comment: @user3683976 please add new question with example

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831216/how-do-i-hide-the-first-column-in-jquery

Comment: @user3683976 you got the answer nice